# How to get a top count for distinct records in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I have a table with a lot of records with some fields duplicated.  I want the most common of each of those duplications.

So, if my table has data like below:

```
 ID     Field1     Field2  
  1      A          10  
  2      A          12 
  3      B          5  
  4      A          10  
  5      B          5  
  6      A          10  
  7      B          8
  8      B          5
  9      A          10
```

I can select distinct and get counts:

```
select distinct Field1, Field2, count(Field1)
from Table
group by Field1, Field2
order by Field1, count(Field1) desc
```

And that will give me

```
Field1    Field2     Count
A         10         4
A         12         1
B          5         3
B          8         1
```

However, I only want the records for each Field1 that have the highest count.  I've been fighting with rank() over partition and subqueries, but haven't found the correct syntax for using two fields for uniqueness and selecting the top record by count.  I've been searching, and I'm sure this has been asked, but I can't find it.

I want to get the following

```
Field1     Field2       (optional) Count 
 A          10           4
 B           5           3
```

The goal is to look at a table that has just a little bit of incorrect data (linking between field1 and field2 wrong) and determine what it SHOULD be based on what it usually is.  I don't know how many bad records there are, so eliminating Count below a certain threshold would work, but seems a bit kludgy.

If it is better, I can make a temp table to put my distinct values into and then select from there, but it doesn't seem like that should be necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select field1, field2, cnt from 
(select field1, field2, cnt, rank() over (partition by field1 order by cnt desc) rnk
from (select distinct Field1, Field2, count(Field1) cnt
            from Table1
            group by Field1, Field2
            order by Field1, count(Field1) desc) 
)
where rnk = 1;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe96d/3

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit inelegant thanks to multiple layers of nested subqueries.  However it should be reasonably efficient.  And it should be reasonably easy to follow the steps in the SQL

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1 id, 'A' field1, 10 field2 from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'A', 12 from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'B', 5 from dual union all
  5    select 4, 'A', 10 from dual union all
  6    select 5, 'B', 5 from dual union all
  7    select 6, 'A', 10 from dual union all
  8    select 7, 'B', 8 from dual union all
  9    select 8, 'B', 5 from dual union all
 10    select 9, 'A', 10 from dual
 11  )
 12  select field1,
 13         field2,
 14         cnt
 15    from (select field1,
 16                 field2,
 17                 cnt,
 18                 rank() over (partition by field1
 19                                  order by cnt desc) rnk
 20           from (select field1, field2, count(*) cnt
 21                   from x
 22                  group by field1, field2))
 23*  where rnk = 1
SQL> /

F     FIELD2        CNT
- ---------- ----------
A         10          4
B          5          3
```

Comment: How did we write the same exact SQL, right down to the aliases for the count and rank? Are you me?

Answer (score 2):

And a third approach ;)

```
select field1,
       field2,
       max_cnt
from (
  select field1, 
         field2, 
         cnt,
         max(cnt) over (partition by field1, field2) as max_cnt,
         row_number() over (partition by field1 order by cnt desc) as rn
  from (
      select field1, 
             field2, 
             count(*) over (partition by Field1, Field2) as cnt
      from idlist
  ) t1 
) t2
where max_cnt = cnt 
and rn = 1
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8461f/1

Comment: This works, although it doesn't seem to be quite as fast as the others.  Thank you.